# Get value of class with dynamic id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the table bellow and I want to get the input `$('.note')` value from the `id` of the previous input :

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id='student_1' class='student'></td> 
    <td><input type="text" class='note'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id='student_2' class='student'></td> 
    <td><input type="text" class='note'></td>
</tr>
```

So it can be something like that :

```
$(".student").change(function () {
    alert(this.id.parent('td input.note').val())
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `closest` and `find`.

```
$(".student").on('change', function () {
   // the student input to which the change event is bound
    var $this = $(this);
    // Get the wrapper in which the inputs are present
    var $closestTr = $this.closest('tr');
    // the input vale that is needed
    alert($closestTr.find('.note').val());

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `this.value` or `$(this).val()` :

```js
$('.classname').on('click',function(){
   console.log(this.value, $(this).val(), this.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='classname' id="id_1" value='value_1'/>
<input type='text' class='classname' id="id_2" value='value_2'/>
<input type='text' class='classname' id="id_3" value='value_3'/>
<input type='text' class='classname' id="id_4" value='value_4'/>
```

**Edit :**

Go up to the parent `tr` using `.closest('tr')` then search for the related input `note` using `.find('.note')` and get the value :

```js
$(".student").on('input', function () {
  console.log( $(this).closest('tr').find('.note').val() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id='student_1' class='student'></td> 
    <td><input type="text" class='note' value="1111"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id='student_2' class='student'></td> 
    <td><input type="text" class='note' value="2222"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer using `input` instead of `change`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this `$('#' + this.id).val()`

You don't need to include the class in the selector because IDs are unique.

Comment: Ah, I missed the part about on click, I agree with Zakaria’s answer.

Comment: You *could* do it that way, sure, but why would not *not* just use `$(this).val()` or `this.value`?

Comment: @DavidThomas Agreed, see my comment above :)